# Trouble understanding inner join

Tags: sql, oracle, join, inner-join

Im trying to understand inner join correct use but im having trouble when I have to call more than 2 tables, im using oracle HR schema for tests, so for example im trying this query:

```sql
select emps.employee_id,
       emps.first_name,
       dep.department_name,
       dep.department_id,
       jh.job_id
from   employees emps
       inner join departments dep
       on emps.department_id = dep.department_id
       inner join job_history jh
       on dep.department_id = jh.department_id;
```

which shows the following result:

[image: query error]

I know its wrong because first its showing duplicate rows, and second if I run this query

```
select * from job_history where employee_id = 100;
```

It shows no results which means that employee 100 (steven) shouldnt be appearing in the results of the first query, I expect first query to show me the results of data that is on employees and also on department and also on job_history which have in common the department_id

HR (human resources schema):

[image: hr schema]

Can anyone help me, what im missing, why it shows duplicate rows?

Comment: You are seeing the result of a Cartesian product, which is what happens when your joins are not set up correctly (recognizing that Cartesian is desirable in a very small subset of use cases). A quick Google search on join syntax will be a good starting point for you. Also check out this excellent question & answer about cartesian products. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30955338/understanding-cartesian-product-in-sql

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: @philipxy The OP states that they are using the HR schema; this is a standard schema generated by Oracle and is freely available to download and install in its entirety and can come pre-installed with the Oracle database (if you pick that setup option).

Comment: @MT0 That doesn't change the fact that they should act on my comments. It isn't even relevant. [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `job_history` table has 3 foreign keys:

1. `employee_id`
2. `job_id`
3. `department_id`

Your `INNER JOIN` only joins on the `DEPARTMENT_ID` so you are matching an employee to the job history for any jobs that occurred for their department but not necessarily jobs specific to that employee. Instead, you probably want to join on either the `employee_id` or the combination of `employee_id` and `department_id`.

So, if you want the jobs history for that employee for any department:

```sql
select emps.employee_id,
       emps.first_name,
       dep.department_name,
       dep.department_id,
       jh.job_id
from   employees emps
       inner join departments dep
       on ( emps.department_id = dep.department_id )
       inner join job_history jh
       on ( emps.employee_id = jh.employee_id );
```

Or, if you want the job history for that employee within that department:

```sql
select emps.employee_id,
       emps.first_name,
       dep.department_name,
       dep.department_id,
       jh.job_id
from   employees emps
       inner join departments dep
       on ( emps.department_id = dep.department_id )
       inner join job_history jh
       on ( emps.employee_id = jh.employee_id
          and emps.department_id = jh.department_id );
```

Comment: I would take it a step further... Emp to JH, JH to Dpt as an employee could have change job departments.  This way he can see where an employee WAS, not just based on the department they are current in now.  Hence the JH has the date of service too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I will check it detailled and understand it :)