# JSON_OBJECT getting called twice in SQL

Tags: mysql, json

I have 4 tables in my database and 5th that acts as a many-to-many table.

1. rooms

```
(
  identifier: VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY
  room_name: VARCHAR
)
```

2. devices

```
(
  identifier: VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY
  friendly_name: VARCHAR
  type: VARCHAR
  gateway: VARCHAR
)
```

3. roomdata

```
(
  room_identifier: VARCHAR FOREIGN KEY
  parameter_key: VARCHAR
  value: VARCHAR
)
```

4. devicedata

```
(
  device_identifier: VARCHAR
  parameter_key: VARCHAR
  value: VARCHAR
)
```

5. (many-to-many table) roomdevices

```
(
  room_identifier: VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY, FOREIGN KEY
  device_identifier: VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY, FOREIGN KEY
)
```

Linking the `rooms` and `devices` tables using the `roomdevices` table works perfectly with this code:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT r.identifier, r.room_name,
    json_arrayagg(JSON_object(
        "identifier", d.identifier,
        "friendly_name", d.friendly_name,
        "type", d.type,
        "gateway", d.gateway
    )) AS devices
FROM rooms AS r
LEFT JOIN roomdevices AS rd ON rd.room_identifier = r.identifier
JOIN devices AS d ON d.identifier = rd.device_identifier
GROUP BY r.identifier
```

But when I try to add the `roomdata` table using this code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.identifier, r.room_name,
    json_arrayagg(JSON_object(
        "key", rdata.parameter_key,
        "value", rdata.value
    )) AS parameters,
    json_arrayagg(JSON_object(
        "identifier", d.identifier,
        "friendly_name", d.friendly_name,
        "type", d.type,
        "gateway", d.gateway
    )) AS devices
FROM rooms AS r
LEFT JOIN roomdevices AS rd ON rd.room_identifier = r.identifier
LEFT JOIN devices AS d ON d.identifier = rd.device_identifier
LEFT JOIN roomdata as rdata ON rdata.room_identifier = r.identifier
GROUP BY r.identifier
```

The response from SQL renders each 'parameter' in the parameters array twice. I assume this is due to that specific room being assigned 2 devices and the json_object initiating twice. But I am not quite sure. I am still fairly new to SQL and would love to learn, but it's hard to find more information online about such a specific problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Remove the DISTINCT ,GROUP by both columns.If this doesnt work check the joins.

Comment: You're accidentally creating a [Cartesian product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30955338/understanding-cartesian-product-in-sql). You should use two separate queries to generate these two results.