# Problem with two sql statement with a different in subquery

Tags: sql, mysql

I have with two sql statements, returning different results, but I do not understand why.

Here is my data
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VTJY.png)

| student | class |
| --- | --- |
| 'A' | 'Math' |
| 'B' | 'English' |
| 'C' | 'Math' |
| 'D' | 'Biology' |
| 'E' | 'Math' |
| 'F' | 'Computer' |
| 'G' | 'Math' |
| 'H' | 'Math' |
| 'I' | 'Math' |

This is the statement 1

```sql
SELECT  class
FROM Courses
WHERE (
  SELECT count(*)
  FROM Courses AS c
  WHERE c.class = Courses.class
) >= 5;
```

This is the result

| class |
| --- |
| 'Math' |
| 'Math' |
| 'Math' |
| 'Math' |
| 'Math' |
| 'Math' |

This is the statement 2

```sql
SELECT  class
FROM Courses
WHERE (
  SELECT count(*)
  FROM Courses AS c, Courses
) >= 5
```

This is the result

| class |
| --- |
| 'Math' |
| 'English' |
| 'Math' |
| 'Biology' |
| 'Math' |
| 'Computer' |
| 'Math' |
| 'Math' |
| 'Math' |

Both of them differ only in the subquery, where statament 2 defines one more "Course" table, but statement 1 not.

Can anyone explain help me

I try to investigate but still do not understand

Comment: Please don't spam the database tags.

Comment: I'm going to assume this is mysql because you mention mysql-workbench.

Comment: Please do some research like [SQL left join vs multiple tables on FROM line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894490/sql-left-join-vs-multiple-tables-on-from-line) and [Bad Habits to Kick: Old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Statement 1 counts all the equal courses. E.g. for student A having a `'Math'` course, it counts all the `'Math'` courses because of the condition in the sub-select `c.class = Courses.class`, where `Courses` denotes the current record of the parent select.

Statement 2 counts all the courses because there is no condition. Worse, since you have two un-joined tales in the FROM clause (`FROM Courses AS c, Courses`), this will create a [Cartesian product](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30955338/880990), i.e.,
it will create all possible pairings of all the records in the two tables. Because the tables have 9 records, `count(*)` will always yield 9 * 9 = 81. It doesn't matter that the "two" tables are the same physical table.

But there is a better way to do this (at least when you don't need to return the `student` column):

```sql
SELECT class
FROM Courses
GROUP BY class
HAVING count(*) >= 5;
```

It will return at most one record per class type instead of one per student. Note that the HAVING clause acts on the grouped result. A WHERE clause would have to be placed before the GROUP BY.

Comment: "Statement 2 counts all the courses.....", **NO**, see: https://dbfiddle.uk/NIC8qLBn    (9*9 = 81)

Comment: @Luuk, good point. I didn't see the problem in the FROM clause.